# Delegating work to two different Delegates, Is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, asihttprequest

I am trying show a `UIProgressView` while downloading an image from a server by using `ASIHTTPRequest`. I want to show progress on the `UIProgressView` which is working perfectly using this code:

```
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressIndicator];
```

I want to show `%` right next to my progress bar, so the user knows what percentage has been downloaded. Some thing like this (I made this in Photoshop):

[image: mockup of desired UI]

---

What I thought of is to use

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes;
```

to update my `UILabel`, This method is always called when ASI request receives some amount of bytes.

But to call this method I have to implement it in my class and then `setDownloadProgressDelegate` to `self`, like this,

```
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
```

Therefore, can I make the `request` object have two different delegates at the same time, so I can receive responses with both? I just need to do some math to calculate the percentage and update my `UILabel` -- I know the exact size of the file I am downloading.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it myself, but could you use KVO to observe the float value of the progress bar, and update the label appropriately?  Not sure if that's possible, though.

Comment: I found the easier way late I can just call [request setDelegate:self]; and [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressViewObject]; to solve my problem. Thanks btw learnt new thing about KVO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours of reading I finally found a easiest way to solve this problem, ASIHTTPRequest has two different method which can help to set delegates.

1. For progress view indicator. - This updates Progress view in short increments it.
2. For class it self. - And this allows to add method in class which called by ASIHTTPRequest object while it finishes it's downloading or uploading.

So what I did is I set my progress view delegate and than I set my self as a delegate of request object. like,

```
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressViewObject]; // For progress view increment
[request setDelegate:self]; // For adding methods such as finished downloading started downloading.
```

---

Mt purpose was to let my request object call below method,

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes; // Now I can increment my UILabel percentage here.
```

Which is messaged periodically by setting,

```
[request setDelegate:self];
```

Hope this will help others in future!

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You want to use NSNotificationCenter. This allows you to loosely couple objects using the pub/sub model. You can post a Notification from an object and any arbitrary number of objects can get the information, without the tight coupling of delegates.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful but later I found an easier way to acheive it :)

Answer (score 2):

Any object can have more than one delegate, you'll just have to keep track of them. So you could have two separate protocols for your two different scenarios, and two `id` variables for each delegate. This is similar to what `UITableView` does with its delegate and datasource, which can be two different objects.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful but later I found an easier way to acheive it :)